# Started optimize table on Magento db, but sites are down. Can I kill it and how?

Tags: mysql, database, magento

All my websites are running super slow because I tried to optimize the Magento DB in phpmyadmin in an effort to get the sites to speed UP. They're so slow they might as well be down. I want the pain to stop. Can I kill the optimize and how would I do that? Or is it better just to wait until it's finished.

For the record, I have a backup of the database.

Comment: Wait until it's finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you can `KILL` any operation you don't want to finish, but be aware that the time to undo the operation may in fact be longer than it takes to simply complete.

Unless you're running a massive installation it sounds like your database needs to be tuned better. MySQL comes with a default `my.cnf` configuration that is terrible, barely any memory allocated to it, and runs slowly.

Secondly, you might be running a lot of queries that are slow because they're missing indexes. How much data is in this table you're trying to optimize? `SHOW TABLE STATUS` will give you an idea.